# Al crear un SP, aparece el mensaje Todas las expresiones GROUP BY deben contener al menos una columna que no sea una referencia exterior

Tags: sql-server

He estado trabajando con una tabla que tiene aproximadamente 30 columnas, y es un tema andar haciendo repetitivamente la consulta para ver cuántos registros tiene cierto grupo de columnas, entonces pensé en crear un Procedimiento Almacenado de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE PROC SP_Distintos(@Columna varchar(255))
AS
BEGIN   
    SELECT @Columna as Columna, COUNT(*), SUM([Importe])
    FROM [Prueba] GROUP BY @Columna
END
```

El tema es que cuando intento crear el SP me manda el siguiente error:

> Todas las expresiones GROUP BY deben contener al menos una columna que
> no sea una referencia exterior.

¿Alguien podría asesorarme del tema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar esto, necesitas usar sql Dinámico.

```
Create table Prueba (col1 varchar(100), col2 varchar(100), importe int);
go
Insert into Prueba (col1, col2, importe)
values
('a','a',100),
('a','a',100),
('a','b',100),
('a','c',100),
('b','a',100);
go
select col1,COUNT(*) as num, SUM(importe)
from prueba
group by col1;
select col2,COUNT(*) as num, SUM(importe)
from prueba
group by col2;
```

Tenemos una tabla con dos columnas y con unas filas. Si ejecutamos la primera select, nos devuelve:

[image: res1]

Si ejecutamos la segunda select:

[image: Res2]

El procedimiento por tanto tendrá que valer para las dos. (En tu caso para las 30)

```
Create procedure dbo.SP_Distintos 
(
@columna nvarchar(128)
)
As
Begin
    Declare @sql nvarchar(2000);
    Set @sql = N'Select '+@columna+N' AS Columna,
        Count(*) as numero, sum(Importe) as importe
        From Prueba
        Group by '+@columna+N';';

    Exec sp_executeSql @sql;
End
```

Datos a tener en cuenta. El parámetro para un nombre de columna no es varchar sino `nvarchar(128)` o `sysname`.

La consulta, se tiene que meter dentro de una variable y ejecutarla con `exec`, `execute` o con el procedure `sp_executeSql` (más recomendable).

Este procedimiento, que es muy interesante, permite pasarle parámetros para darle fortaleza, para que nadie pueda hacerte **sql inyection**. Pero es algo más complicado. Te recomiendo, que lo hagas, porque sino, en el parámetro al procedure, le puede llegar cualquier cosa y tendrás problemas.

[Sql dinámico. ¿Cómo se hace?](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2021/02/03/sql-dinamico-como-se-hace/)

```
Exec dbo.SP_Distintos N'Col1'
```

[image: Res3]

```
Exec dbo.SP_Distintos N'Col2';
```

[image: res4]

Una mejora adicional, es preguntarle a la vista de Information_Schema si el nombre recibido es un valor adecuado para un nombre de columna.

```
Alter procedure dbo.SP_Distintos 
(
@columna nvarchar(128)
)
As
Begin
    IF (EXISTS(SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where 
        TABLE_NAME = N'PRUEBA' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = @columna
    ))
    BEGIN
        Declare @sql nvarchar(2000);
        Set @sql = N'Select '+@columna+N' AS Columna,
            Count(*) as numero, sum(Importe) as importe
            From Prueba
            Group by '+@columna+N';';

        Exec sp_executeSql @sql;
    END
    Else
        Select 'No se está ejecutando adecuadamente el procedure';
End
```

Ahora si le pides una columna que no es de la tabla.

```
Exec dbo.SP_Distintos N'Col22'
```

[image: Res5]

En el else, podrías hacer cualquier otra cosa, ya que la tienes identificada.